# Distance of a point from a straight line in $\Bbb R^2$: are there other simple proofs?

Tags: analytic-geometry, solution-verification

To demonstrate the distance of a point from a straight line I generally use these two proofs. I apologize with all users if they are handwritten and not in `MathJaX`. I ask you if anyone knows any other simple way to get other proofs.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vectors a simple way is this. The equation of the line in vector notation is
$$
(a, b) \begin{pmatrix}
x\\y
\end{pmatrix}=-c
\tag 1$$
that say:

*the  projection of a point of the line in the direction of $(a,b)^{\intercal}$ is*  $$-c/\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \tag 2$$

That is: the (signed) distance of the line from the origin is $-c/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Now take a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$. The projection of its distance from the origin in the same direction is

$$
(a, b) \begin{pmatrix}
x_0\\y_0
\end{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \tag 3
$$

so the distance of the point $P$ from the line is the absolute value of the difference:
$$
\frac{ax_0+by_0}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} - \frac{
-c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} 
$$

---

[image]

In the picture:
$ OB$ is the vector $(a,b) ^T$ (I use the Transpose because a vector is a column). The length of $\overline{OC}$ is $-c/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, so the line $DC$ is $ ax+by=-c$.
$P$ is the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and $\overline{OP'}= (ax_0+by_0)/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. From these we can find $\overline{P'C}$

Comment: It took me two months for my third-year students to explain the vectors. I don't quite understand the number (2) and the successive steps (as first approach). The directories numbers $(l,m)=(a,b)$ of a straight line is a vector perpendicular to it. Why do you take the transposed $(a,b)^{\intercal}$? Please, can you put a picture or image? +1

Comment: I agree ! To explain vectors is not easy, but it is a powerful tool ! Anyway, I added a picture. I hope it's useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. But $\overline{OC}=|c|/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$? Why you put $-c/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$? The answer are all very nice. For your opinion what must I put the green check mark? I vote always ...all :-) abundantly :-)

Comment: $-c$ because I used the *signed* distance.

Comment: What is the signed distance? :-( My english has a low level.

Comment: Distanza con segno. Per capire da che parte si trova la retta rispetto all'origine.

Answer (score 2):

This method is not too much shorter, but it's quite neat, so I thought I'd share it.

The problem can be written as

\begin{cases}
\text{Minimize } & (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 \\
\text{Subject to } & ax+by+c=0
\end{cases}

Thus, we use Lagrange Multipliers by considering the function

$$F(x,y,\lambda) = (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2-\lambda(ax+by+c)$$

Setting $\nabla F=\mathbf 0$, we obtain

\begin{align}
2(x-x_0)-\lambda a & = 0 \\
2(y-y_0) - \lambda b & = 0 \\
ax+by+c & = 0
\end{align}

Rewrite the equations as

\begin{align}
(x-x_0) & = \frac{\lambda a}{2} & \\
(y-y_0) & = \frac{\lambda b}{2} \\
a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0) & = -(ax_0+by_0+c)
\end{align}

Plug the first two equations into the third to obtain

$$\frac{\lambda a^2}{2} + \frac{\lambda b^2}{2} = -(ax_0+by_0+c) \implies \lambda = \frac{-2(ax_0+by_0+c)}{a^2+b^2}$$

From this, we obtain the required distance to be

$$\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2 a^2}{4} + \frac{\lambda^2 b^2}{4}} = \frac{|\lambda|}{2}\sqrt{a^2+b^2} = \frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: Wonderful! My sincere compliments. I have forgotten that the eventual proofs are for my students. Very nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given a circle representing the distance from $(x_0,y_0$) as

$$
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2-r^2=0
$$

and a line as

$$
a x+b y+c=0
$$

assuming $b\ne 0$, taking from the line

$$
y = -\frac{a x+c}{b}
$$

and substituting into the distance equation we have

$$
\left(\frac{a x+c}{b}+y_0\right)^2-r^2+(x-x_0)^2=0
$$

solving for $x$ we have

$$
x = \frac{b \left(b x_0\pm\sqrt{r^2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)-(a x_0+b y_0+c)^2}\right)-a (b y_0+c)}{a^2+b^2}
$$

now if $x$ represents the tangency point between the circle and the line (orthogonal projection), it should have an unique value hence we need

$$
r^2 \left(a^2+b^2\right)-(a x_0+b y_0+c)^2=0
$$

or in other words

$$
r = \frac{|a x_0+b y_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$

Comment: Great answer, too. Really my most sincere compliments also to you that I give to you again.

Answer (score 1):

[image]This is what I used during high school. Let us say that we want to find minimum distance from point $A$ with coordinate $(x_0 , y_0)$ to line $ax+by+c=0$.

Say that point $C$ lie on the line such that $|AC|$ is minimum. Draw vertical line through $A$ and intersect the line at $B$ with coordinate $(x_0 , y_1)$.

Key take away:

$\frac{|AC|}{|AB|}=|\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}}|$

$|AB|=|y_{0}-y_{1}|=\frac{|ax_0 + by_0 + c|}{|b|}$

substitute to the first equation to obtain Your result.

In case it is not clear enough, $ax_0 + by_0 + c = ax_0 + by_1 + c + b(y_0 - y_1) =b(y_0 - y_1)$ since $(x_0 , y_1)$ is on the line.

If the line is vertical, we can draw horizontal line through $A$ instead and proceed with similar steps with the same result.

Comment: Meanwhile...thank you very much. Please, can you put a image to be more clear?

Comment: I am away from my tablet or laptop, will do when i have access to them

Comment: @Sebastiano i hope the picture is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

If You are familiar with vectors, i think this is a good food for thought.

We want the shortest distance between point $A$ and line $\nabla{L}\cdot\vec{X}+c=0$. Suppose $B$ lies on the line, we can project vector $\vec{A}-\vec{B}$ to vector $\frac{\nabla{L}}{|\nabla{L}|}$ to obtain the shortest distance.

$$
d_{min}=\left|\frac{\nabla{L}}{|\nabla{L}|}\cdot(\vec{A}-\vec{B})\right|=\frac{\left|\nabla{L}\cdot{\vec{A}}+c\right|}{|\nabla{L}|}
$$

Comment: I have understood your explanations....but my question it is for my students of 16 years old. However I have voted all answers.