# Distance of a point from a straight line in $\Bbb R^2$: doubts when I use the implicit form of a straight line $r$

Tags: proof-explanation, analytic-geometry

Referring to a recent question at this link [Distance of a point from a straight line in $\Bbb R^2$: are there other simple proofs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567138/distance-of-a-point-from-a-straight-line-in-bbb-r2-are-there-other-simple-p), I have used the implicit form of $r$ to have the formula:

[image]

$$d(P_0,r)=\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \tag 1$$

Let be a straight line $r: ax+by+c=0$ and $P_0(x_0,y_0)\notin r$ I want to find the distance $P_0$ from $r$, called $d(P_0,r)$. Let be a straight line $s$ perpendicular to $r$ through to $P_0$:
$$s: b(x-x_0)-a(y-y_0)$$
$$
\begin{cases}
   ax+by+c=0 &\\
   b(x-x_0)-a(y-y_0)=0 &
\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases}
   y=-\dfrac ab x -\dfrac cb&\\
   bx-bx_0-a\left(-\dfrac ab x-\dfrac cb-y_0\right)=0&
\end{cases} 
$$

With some steps we find

$$
H\equiv\left(\dfrac{b^2x_0-ac-ay_0b}{a^2+b^2};-\dfrac ab \left(\dfrac{b^2x_0-ac-ay_0b}{a^2+b^2}\right)-\dfrac cb\right)
$$
where $\{H\}=r\cap s$. Therefore $d(P_0,H)\equiv d(P_0,r)$ is given by

$$ d(P_0,r)=\sqrt{\left(x_0+\frac{ac+ay_0b-b^2x_0}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(y_0+\left(\frac ab \left(\frac{b^2x_0-ac-ay_0b}{a^2+b^2}+\frac cb\right)\right)\right)^2} \tag 2$$
If $P_0\equiv O\equiv (0,0)$ we find into the square root (with other steps)

$$\frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{b^2}c^2(a^2+b^2)}{\require{cancel}\cancel{b^2}(a^2+b^2)}=\frac{c^2}{a^2+b^2}$$

Hence

$$d(O,r)=\frac{|c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} , \quad (\text{correct!})$$

But with the $(2)$ there are many long algebraic steps which should give the $(2)$. Is there any condition that I should use to delete some terms?

Comment: If you replace $ay_0$ with the correct value $aby_0$ the expression for $H $ can be written in a symmetric way.

Comment: @user Is there into my question some mistakes? :-(

Comment: I don't know if it is a mistake or a misprint. Probably the former.

Comment: @user I have checked the handwritten passages first by hand and then they written in MathJaX. But it all seems correct to me.

Comment: I have already pointed out the error in the first comment. Can you find it?

Comment: @user Thank you very much...finded it!

Comment: Now simplify the expression for the $y $ coordinate of the point $H $.

Comment: Please can you write an answer thus I have given to you a upvoted? Thank you...see you now the reputation.

Comment: Near the beginning of your derivation, you make the tacit assumption that $b\ne0$. If it is, your expression for $y$ is undefined, as are many of the successive expressions in the derivation.

Comment: Also unstated in this question is how you define the distance between a point and line in the first place. You’re proceeding as if it’s the length of the altitude from the given point, but is that the definition that you’re working from or an unproven assumption that this segment will give the minimum distance to a point on the line?

Comment: It is evident that $b\neq0$.

Comment: @Sebastiano Really? How so? All that’s stated is that we’re given the implicit equation of a line, with no further restrictions on the coefficients. I don’t see anything that excludes vertical lines here. Moreover, your proof is incomplete if you exclude this case.

Comment: If your students have learned Cramer’s rule for solving system of linear equations, I’d recommend using that since it’s completely general: it doesn’t require that $b\ne0$ as your proof does. It does require that at least one of $a$ or $b$ be nonzero, but that’s necessary for the original equation to represent a line in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! The derivation can be found in the answer of @amd. Have a nice day!

Comment: @user Thank you very much and also for you a great nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re making a tacit assumption that $b\ne0$. Without that, many of the expressions in your derivation are undefined. Even if you make this assumption explicit, the proof is incomplete without also considering this case. If your students have learned Cramer’s rule for solving systems of linear equations, I recommend using that because it’s completely general and doesn’t involve a case analysis: it only requires that at least one of $a$ or $b$ is nonzero, which you also need for the original implicit equation to represent a line in the first place.

The system of linear equations to be solved is, after rearranging $$ax+by=-c \\ bx-ay = bx_0-ay_0.$$ Using Cramer’s rule, we therefore have $$x_h = {\begin{vmatrix}-c&b\\bx_0-ay_0&-a\end{vmatrix} \over \begin{vmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{vmatrix}} = {b^2x_0-aby_0-ac\over a^2+b^2} \\
y_h = {\begin{vmatrix}a&-c\\b&bx_0-ay_0\end{vmatrix}\over\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\b&-a\end{vmatrix}} = {a^2y_0-abx_0-bc\over a^2+b^2}.$$

That aside, if following your derivation I would first simplify the expression for $y_H$ to the one above before computing the distance between the points. The necessary algebraic manipulations for the distance to a general point $P$ then don’t seem very daunting: $$x_0-x_H = {(a^2x_0+b^2x_0)-(b^2x_0-aby_0-ac)\over a^2+b^2} = {a(ax_0+by_0+c)\over a^2+b^2}$$ and similarly $$y_0-y_H = {b(ax_0+by_0+c)\over a^2+b^2}.$$ Squaring and adding produces $${(a^2+b^2)(ax_0+by_0+c)^2\over(a^2+b^2)^2}$$ and the rest is obvious.

Comment: Yes I'm agree with you that "*The necessary algebraic manipulations for the distance to a general point P then don’t seem very daunting*"...but I have not used Cramer's rule because my students not remember it. My consideration: I look that in these days or in this morning I can to find a strategy to reduce the $(2)$ because I want obtain the solution by the $(2)$. Meanwhile thank you very much and....give you +1 and check green mark.

Comment: @Sebastiano As I mentioned in the latter half of this answer, an effective way to reduce (2) is to first simplify the expression that you obtained for $y_H$. This will give you the same expression that I obtained via Cramer’s rule above. Then, if you spot the similarity in the expressions for $x_H$ and $y_H$, after simplifying $x_0-x_H$ you can just about write down the simplified expression for $y_0-h_H$ directly. Factoring before squaring helps a lot, too, as it makes common factors evident.

Comment: I have appreciated lot lot your code and comments...also adding other reputations to you.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious, why didn’t You proceed this way:

$$
\begin{aligned}
b(x-x_{0})-a(y-y_{0})=0\rightarrow&\ (x-x_{0})=am\\
&\ (y-y_{0})=bm
\end{aligned}
$$

Where the distance is $d(P_{0},r)=\sqrt{(x-x_{0})^{2}-(y-y_{0})^{2}}\ \ =\sqrt{a^{2}+b^{2}}\ \ |m|$

$$
\begin{aligned}
ax_{0}+by_{0}+c&=a(x_{0}-x)+b(y_{0}-y)+ax+by+c\\
&= a(x_{0}-x)+b(y_{0}-y)\\
&=-a^{2}m-b^{2}m
\end{aligned}
$$

and therefore, $\frac{\left|ax_{0}+by_{0}+c\right|}{\sqrt{\ (a^{2}+b^{2})}}\ \ =d(P_{0}\ ,r)$

Comment: Thank you very much again ....This morning my students want the proof like my question.

Comment: @Sebastiano fair enough, You’re welcome!